# SQL select all pairs of ID numbers where they do not work together

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Given a table of the following form:

```
EMPLOYEE: ID, ProjectNum, Hours
```

Where ID and ProjectNum together make up the primary key, I would like to be able to output all of the pairs of ID numbers such that they do not work together on any project (an employee can work on more than one project).

I believe this can be done with some kind of join of the table to itself but I am struggling to work out how to only output the results where ProjectNum1 <> ProjectNum2 as clearly this could be the case for one project but not another.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You search all the pair, and filter those working together in one project.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       e1.id as emp1, 
       e2.id as emp2
FROM Employee e1
JOIN Employee e2
  ON e1.id < e2.id
WHERE not exist ( SELECT 1
                  FROM Employee r1
                  JOIN Employee r2
                    ON r1.id < r2.id
                   AND r1.ProjectNum = r2.ProjectNum 
                   AND e1.ID = r1.ID
                   AND e2.ID = r2.ID
                )
```

You use `e1.id < e2.id` instead of `e1.id <> e2.id` so you don't get inverted pairs

Comment: You probably need a `select distinct` in the outer query to avoid duplicates, given the data structure.

Comment: Btw I think your employee table should be called `employee_projects` and if you have a table with the employee info like name, phone, etc. use that as the base to create the pairs. Because that table is smaller will be better for performance